# Making twitter bootstrap full-width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sidebar

I'm trying to create a simple website that's responsive and has a right sidebar.

Preferably I would like the right sidebar to stack at the top on mobile devices.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/wyLTA/embedded/result/

**What do I need to change to make it full width, and not stuck on the left?**

Comment: An aside: this is where using grid systems that require 'span3' or similar fall down. In your "mobile" layout you obviously don't want it to be 3 columns (and at larger widths you may want it less than 3), and so class names like that quickly get confusing. I suggest looking for a grid system that doesn't do this, such as Susy (for Compass).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, moving from `span6` to `span9` did the trick.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/wyLTA/9/embedded/result/

[though still want to know how to make sidebar stack up to top instead of bottom]

Comment: You'll need to tweak the margins but if you swap the position of the content and sidebar in your markup, then apply `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes you can get the sidebar to appear at the top. You'll need to adjust some margins though: http://jsfiddle.net/wyLTA/32/embedded/result/

Answer (score 5):

add `<div class="span3" id="sidebar"> ... </div>` before your .span6 and the following css / jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        ...
```

**CSS:**

```
#sidebar{
  background-color:#555555;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  margin-bottom:9px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
function sidebar() {
  var windowwidth=$(window).width();
  if(windowwidth>=768) $("#sidebar").css('position','absolute')
  else $("#sidebar").css('position','relative')
}
$(document).ready(sidebar);
$(window).resize(sidebar);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/wyLTA/8/

---

Or with media queries

**CSS:**

```
#sidebar{
  background-color:#555555;
  right:0px; 
  margin-bottom:9px;
} 

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #sidebar{
    position:relative;       
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar{
    position:absolute;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wyLTA/11/
​

Comment: Thanks, that works, but is there a way to do it without JavaScript?

Comment: it's even easier with media queries after all. (updated answer)